# What is the principle behind this set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this question, and I do not understand how I can conclude which set the result will be in based on the information given. Can someone please explain the process one can use to get to the answer?

We saw that the difference of integers selected from the set $[0]$, $[1]$, or $[2]$ results in a multiple of $3$.  For example, for $-6$ and $9$ from $[0]$, their sum $3$ is in $[0]$.  What about the sum of two integers from different sets $[0]$, $[1]$ or $[2]$?  Say, select an integer from set $[1]$ and another from set $[2]$. Is their sum in $[0]$, $[1]$ or $[2]$?

Answer (score 1):

I presume the notation $[i]$ means the set of integers that are equivalent to $i \mod{3}$. Observe that if $k \in [i]$ then $k=3l+i$, where $l$ is an integer. Consequently, $a \in [1]$ and $b \in [2]$ implies $a+b = 3 x+1+3y+2 = 3(x+y+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. Consequently, $a+b \in [0]$.

In general, if $a \in [i]$, $b \in [j]$, and $i+j \in [k]$ then $a+b \in [k]$. For example, $a \in [0]$, and $b \in [2]$ imply that $a+b \in [2]$.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is that the equivalence relation $\equiv$ that defines the sets $[0],[1],[2]$ (i.e. the relation $m\equiv n$ if $m-n$ is a multiple of $3$) is compatible with the addition of integers, in the following sense:

Whenever $a\equiv b$ and $c\equiv d$, we can deduce that $a+c\equiv b+d$.

So when you take an integer $a$ from $[1]$ and another integer $b$ from $[2]$, since $a\equiv 1$ and $b\equiv 2$, we have $a+b\equiv1+2\equiv0$, i.e. $a+b\in[0]$.

For a more general setting of the phenomenon "equivalence relation compatible with binary operation", you will need to learn group theory. Here, the equivalence relations compatible with binary operation are exactly determined by normal subgroups, and the elements $[0],[1],[2]$ are known as elements in the quotient group determined by a normal subgroup of integers.